# How can I get the current playing time from an embedded video on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming

How can I get the current playing time from an embedded video on a webpage?  Is there simply an attribute that can be obtained using JavaScript from one of the common embedded video players?  Or do I need to do a work-around like make my own pause and play buttons and keep track of time manually while feeding the play/pause commands to the video using JavaScript?  The latter is much more ugly in my opinion.  Other solutions?

Comment: 29% accept!  How discouraging for anyone who wants to answer...

Comment: People haven't given me good answers, it's not my fault!

Comment: Answers like "you shouldn't ask that question" are not going to get a vote or accept, and I get a lot of those.  I'll bet I'll even get one here.  "You should just use Flash instead", or "Why would you want to do that?"

Comment: There are quite a few ways to embed a video on a web page. Can you tell us the approach you're using?

Comment: Probably something like the good old embed tag, or the object version of that.  Nothing fancy.

Comment: I'm open to alternatives, however...

Comment: This question is not relevant to embedded programming - the tag wiki explicitly says that the embedded tag does NOT apply to components embedded on a web page, see stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded

Answer (score 0):

The html5 video tag provides some decent support for this kind of thing.

The following page gives some decent ideas:
http://www.broken-links.com/2009/10/06/building-html5-video-controls-with-javascript/

Comment: What about without using html5?